# Js decrementing will not work properly after one use

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a game  where you need to fly your character around to get bombs. When you touch the bomb, a math equation is shown. If the user gets it right, one bomb from a bar of bombs will disappear.

I coded this using a let variable that corresponds with the amount of bombs shown on the bomb bar.

If I get the first math question right, it will work correctly and remove one bomb(so there is now 4 bombs shown on the bar). However the second time, it will show 2 bombs, when it's supposed to show 3. Then the next time it will go to 0. After multiple debugging attempts I've noticed that the first time it will work, then the second time it will decrement the "bombnum" by 2 instead of 1. (for ex, I set the bombnum to equal 4. The bombs were 3,1,then 0. If I set it to 5, its 4,2, then 0)

(bombnum is equal to the integer 5 in the code shown below)

Does anyone have any tips/suggestions/fixes to this? Anything is appreciated, thank you.

Home.js(only the submit and checking bombs event)

```
function checkQ(){
  /* getting the value when the user presses submit */
  searchV =  Number(search.value) 
  /* determining which operator a random function chose
  to properly determine the answer of the equation
   and compare it to
  what the user submitted */
  switch(newop){
    case '+':
      
    if(searchV == firstN + secondN){
      --bombnum

      if(bombnum == 4){
        bombs.innerText = ' '
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
        
      }else if(bombnum == 3){
      
        bombs.innerText = '  '
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
        
      }else if(bombnum == 2){
      
        bombs.innerText = '   '
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
        
      }else if(bombnum == 1){
       
        bombs.innerText = '    '
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
        
      }else{
        bombs.innerText = '     '
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
    }}
    break;

    case '-':
    if(searchV == firstN - secondN){
      --bombnum

      if(bombnum == 4){
       
        bombs.innerText = ''
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
        
      }else if(bombnum == 3){
       
        bombs.innerText = ''
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
        
      }else if(bombnum == 2){
        
        bombs.innerText = ''
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
        
      }else if(bombnum == 1){
        
        bombs.innerText = ''
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
        
      }else{
        bombs.innerText = ''
        equation.classList.add('hide')
        spawngameEle()
        spawnBomb()
    }}
    break;
    case 'x':
      if(searchV == firstN * secondN){
        --bombnum
        if(bombnum == 4){
         
          bombs.innerText = ''
          equation.classList.add('hide')
          spawngameEle()
          spawnBomb()
          
        }else if(bombnum == 3){
          
          bombs.innerText = ''
          equation.classList.add('hide')
          spawngameEle()
          spawnBomb()
          
        }else if(bombnum == 2){
          
          bombs.innerText = ''
          equation.classList.add('hide')
          spawngameEle()
          spawnBomb()
          
        }else if(bombnum == 1){
          
          bombs.innerText = ''
          equation.classList.add('hide')
          spawngameEle()
          spawnBomb()
          
        }else{
          bombs.innerText = ''
          equation.classList.add('hide')
          spawngameEle()
          spawnBomb()
      }}
      break;
    
  }
}
}
```

Comment: my guess is you are adding multiple listeners so the function runs twice the 2nd time, and 3 times the third time...

Comment: Your function seems to do what you want it to do. are you sure you don't call it too much ? I will also add a few advice: First, try to use === in JS instead of ==, in general it is far less error prone. Second, try to avoid repetitions, especially when you could try to find a pattern to avoid it. Here, you could replace all your bombnum checks that varies just because of the bombs innertext by `if(bombnum < 5 && bombnum >= 0) { bombs.innerText = "".repeat(bombnum) + " ".repeat(5 - bombnum); }` for example (and then you add the 3 function calls)

Comment: Please show us how the function is called.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I am very sorry, for some reason my comment didnt post. Yes, that was the problem. I removed the 2nd addeventlistener and it worked fine